# jquery ckeditor language dir

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can i define the language dir in this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                         $('#Header1').ckeditor();

                     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#<%=OrganizationMeta.vcr_MetaKey + Lang.int_LangId%>')
                      .ckeditor(function () { /* callback code */ }, { contentsLangDirection: '<%=TempData["Direction"] %>' });
                     });
                  </script>
```